# Displaying an integer to hex in C

Tags: c, casting, integer, printf, hex

I have this part of code in C class:

```
int i;
    for (i=0;i<val;i++)
        mdl_print ("%u ", rec->payload[i]);
    mdl_print ("\n");
```

Variable rec->payload is uint8_t type. I would print it in hexadecimal notation.

How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: presumably `mdl_print()` takes any format string that `printf()` takes?

Comment: yes ;) I rewritten for my personal use

Comment: I don't see how this question warrants a down-vote. It's not all that clear how to correctly convert *uintN_t* to strings of decimal digits, as evidenced by the number of incorrect answers to this question. How many answers were written by people who have read 7.21.6.1 p8 and p9? Evidently, none.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First your title is so wrong... `Casting integer to hex in C` casting implies a type change, hex is a number system not a type. You're "displaying an integer in hex" not "casting". If you don't understand the difference please ask for clarification.

As far as the displaying goes, it depends what you want the result to look like. One short cut that I typically use is:

```
mdl_print("%#x ", rec->payload[i]);
```

Which displays values as:

```
0xA6
```

The caveat on this syntax is that it doesn't work with 0, you don't get `0x0` just `0`. So an alternative would be:

```
mdl_print("0x%x ", rec->payload[i]);
```

Which will display the value as `0xA6` or `0x0` or whatever it maybe. Of course if you don't want the `0x` part you can always just do:

```
mdl_print("%x ", rec->payload[i]);
```

Your max value (in hex) with a unsigned 8-bit number is `0xFF` so if you want them all to display the same "width" you can use the size specifier too:

```
mdl_print("%02x ", rec->payload[i]); // or mdl_print("0x%02x, rec->payload[i]); 
                                     // or whatever you picked
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and easy:

```
print("%x", (int)(rec->payload[i]));
```

To display in the format 0x05 then use:

```
print("0x%02x", ...)
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

If mdl_print() works like the standard C function printf(), try something like the following:

```
printf( "%02x", (int) rec->payload[i] );
```

The basic printf formatting code for writing in hexadecimal is %x. "02" means to pad the number with '0' until it's two characters wide, which is how you'd normally print an int8.

Many custom output functions follow the format of printf in this way, since it's very familiar to C programmers. You can read more about printf on its man page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Answer (score 1):

Use "%x", so:

mdl_print ("%x ", rec->payload[i]);

This will give you a hex number that is the "length necessary". If you want a fixed length, use "%02x" for two digits padded with zeros.

Comment: The argument should be explicitly converted to an `unsigned int`, if it functions anything like formatted printing in standard C: `mdl_printf("%x", (unsigned int) rec->payload[i]);`. Proof from 7.21.6.1p8 of n1570.pdf: "The unsigned int argument is converted to ... unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X)".

Answer (score 1):

Note that providing a `uint8_t` or `int` where an `unsigned int` is expected in printf is undefined behaviour, as stated by section 7.21.6.1p9 of n1570.pdf: "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." According to 7.21.6.1p8, `%x` tells printf to expect an `unsigned int`. Make sure you explicitly cast your `uint8_t` to `(unsigned int)`, or use the `PRIx8` macro found in `<stdint.h>`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    uint8_t foo = 42;
    /* These two printfs are equivalent: */
    printf("Hex for %02u: %02x\n", (unsigned int) foo, (unsigned int) foo);
    printf("Hex for %02" PRIu8 ": %02" PRIx8 "\n", foo, foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read section 7.20 (Integer types) of the same document. A `uint8_t` *is* a valid integer type and thus does *not* lead to UB

Comment: @Mike, when put as such an `unit8_t` is converted to an `int` and not an unsigned, so 'modifiable lvalue' is correct that one should take care of that.

Comment: @JensGustedt ok, could you or modifiable lvalue then explain that a little further. 7.21.6 p8 says `x` takes an `unsigned int` argument. 7.20.1.1(2 &3) states that a typedef name `uintN_t` designates an unsigned int type and the implementation provides 8 bits as one of the widths. So how is it that a `uint8_t` is *not* an unsigned int? Where is the conversion to signed int noted? and that an explicit typecast solves this?

Comment: for implicit conversion all narrow types are converted to `int` as long as all values fit into it. BTW, this conversion is applied whenever a narrow type is used in an arithmetic expression or passed to a function without prototype (such as `printf`).

Comment: @Mike 7.20.1.1p2 mentions "unsigned integer type", *not* "`unsigned int`". 7.21.6p8 *specifically* mentions "`unsigned int`". Is `sizeof (uint8_t) == sizeof (unsigned int)`? No. 6.5.2.2p6 implies that *integer promotions* are applied to arguments of function calls like printf. "*If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
bit-field), the value is converted to an int; ...*" so the argument is actually an *int*.